# Pointer to the beginning of Linkedlist is changing while adding a new node to the end

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I was playing with the simple Linkedlist traversal code in an iterative way. But I was getting `segmentation fault`. With some debugging I found that the `start` pointer through which I was intending to store the address of the first node was changing with each new node addition from a vector. Couldn't figure out why ?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Node {
    public:
    int data;
    Node* link;
};
Node* start = NULL;

void ab(int data) {
    Node temp;
    temp.data = data;
    temp.link = NULL;
    if (start == NULL) {
        start = &temp;
        cout << "YES" << " "; // for debugging 
    } 
    else {
        Node* ptr;
        ptr = start;
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            ptr = ptr->link;
        }
        ptr = &temp;
    }
    cout << start->data << " "; // for printing the data of start
}

void gen(vector<int>& v) {
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
        ab(v[i]);
    }
}

void show() {
    Node* ptr = start;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        cout << ptr->data << " ";
        ptr = ptr->link;
    } 
    return;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n; // input: 5
    vector<int> v(n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cin >> v[i]; // input: 5 4 3 2 1
    }
    gen(v);
    show();
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output is:

```
[1]    28937 segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But if I comment out the `show()` function, the output will change to this:

```
YES 5 4 3 2 1
```

So, its going against my intention of storing the address of only the first node in the `start` pointer. But nowhere I have tried to change the value of `start` pointer, after adding the first node. So why it is changing ?

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `temp` with `new`. Linking to the address of a local `Node` will cause ub.

Comment: For a linked list, you need to use dynamic memory allocation, i.e. `new` and `delete`

Comment: When I am creating the object of the `Node` class, there should be auto allocation of the memory to the `temp` object right ? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Maybe try to go on Code Review and look at the list examples there

Comment: Nope, right now, you have a pointer. A pointer points to memory, but doesn't create it. To actually create a Node that won't go out of scope, you have to dynamically allocated it.

Comment: @aji13 Sure, But then when `temp` goes out of scope at the end of `ab`, it no longer exists. So now you've stored a pointer to an object that no longer exists. You can't dereference a pointer to an object that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem

```
void ab(int data) {
    Node temp;
    temp.data = data;
    temp.link = NULL;
    ...
}
```

The Node object is created in stack, so it will be destroyed at the end of scope. You need create it in heap by `new` operator.

```
void ab(int data) {
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->link = nullptr;
    ...
}
```

Note: Remember to `delete` all node when you don't need the Linked List anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dynamic allocation as Minh in above answer suggested.

It's because after ab() finishes, "temp" doesn't exist(becomes out-of-scope) so when you're taking "start" as a pointer again in show(),it actually doesn't exist.

Hope you have understood!